# IDE для Lisp под Linux

Tags: lisp, ide

Не посоветуете нормальный IDE с гуем?
Еще бы хорошо литературу.

Answer (score 5):

Смотря что вы имели ввиду говоря "lisp".

- **Common Lisp**. В lisp среде крайне популярна связка [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) + [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/). Кроме того ещё есть коммерческий [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/) с ограниченной бесплатной версией.

**Литература.**

[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).
   ([Перевод на русский](http://lisper.ru/pcl/))

- **Scheme**. Тут довольно популярен [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) который ранее назывался PLT Scheme. Кроме того есть множество плагинов для Emacs для работы с Scheme. [Здесь](http://alexott.net/ru/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsScheme.html) довольно подробный обзор.

**Литература**.

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).
   ([Перевод на русский](http://1sm.ru/sicp.pdf))

[The Scheme Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/)

Вообще, Emacs крайне популярен у лисперов, т.к. он сам большей частью написан на диалекте лиспа Emacs Lisp.

Что имелось ввиду под "IDE c гуем" я не понял.

Comment: > Что имелось ввиду под "IDE c гуем" я не понял.

может нужно как делфи, только на лиспе?:)

Answer (score 1):

1. EMACS
2. SLIME - динамическая документация

Comment: Вот только с гуем в emacs проблемы.

Comment: Это проблемы почти во всех остальных. В EMACS лучший GUI - он не заметен, не отвлекает, гибок и работает идеально. https://github.com/11111000000/tao-theme-emacs

Comment: Здорово выглядит! Мне правда нравится. Только подозреваю, что ТС предполагал нечто другое (независимые окошки).

Comment: - oh yeah... good ol' `C-x 5 2`

- dammit, emacs!

https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/real_programmers.png

Comment: @11111000000 Вы сами конфигурировали или сборка готовая? Spasemacs = Emacs + Vim хорошая сборка отлаженные "слои" под все основные языки, не только Lisp, удобный конфиг в одном файле.

Comment: я по-старинке, сам, но спэйсмэкс неплох, для начала. Кстати, вим-сочетания можно в нём вырубить, что кстати рекомендую сделать, если нет вим-привыкания

Answer (score 0):

насчет "IDE с гуем" еще есть способ [Installing Cusp with SBCL and Eclipse IDE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3dy_XVPZw4)